# Oracle: PLSQL with classes

Tags: oracle, class

I want to use the typical java notation.
I need a Timer but I don't want to create a Package with just two variable (start and finish time, and a few methods).

Can I create a inline package, type or record that can contain functions?

Comment: Why don't you want to create a package?  Anyway, PL/SQL does not support the concept of "inline" or disposable program units.

Comment: A package just for timer? In c# and Java you have thousand classes but you can organize them in folder. Oracle just uses schema and the db I work has already got a very large number of packages.

Comment: Sure, why not?  Having many small cohesive packages is better than a handful of large sprawling packages called UTILS or MISC.  But I agree that when the number of packages gets to EBS levels it is pretty stupid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use objects:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE timer  AS OBJECT
(
  start_time  DATE
, end_time    DATE 
, CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION timer
  RETURN SELF AS RESULT
, MEMBER FUNCTION get_duration
  RETURN NUMBER
)
;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY timer IS


  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION timer      
  RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELF.start_time := SYSDATE;
    RETURN;
  END;

  MEMBER FUNCTION get_duration
  RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN  NVL(SELF.end_time, SYSDATE) - SELF.start_time;
  END get_duration;

END;
/
```

Comment: Not sure there's much added value from instantiating an object rather than using a PL/SQL package.

Comment: @APC it is possible to have multiple instances of an object type in the same session

Comment: I know that.  I just think it's incredibly rare to need multiple timers in the same session.